# Searching help pages is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, help-center

Searching for anything in the help center results in a `Oops! Something Bad Happened!`.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=minimal
https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=reproducible
https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=something
https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=just+anything+at+all

> [image]

Comment: Search cluster is a little unhappy right now, SRE are looking into it

Comment: An even worse regression of [Searching on Help Center doesn't return anything network-wide](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/367060/289905)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon one of the search nodes keeps jumping off the network and shards aren’t re-allocating properly. Our SRE team is looking into it, although we’re a little understaffed because of the US holidays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up, one of the nodes that runs our search cluster kept diving off the network and there was some... odd misconfiguration issues that prevented it gracefully re-entering the cluster. Our SRE team addressed the underlying issues and things are stable again. Apologies for the inconvenience!