# intags:mine stopped working yesterday

Tags: bug, search

When searching using `intags:mine`, I can see questions only until 21 hours ago

Although when checking on specific tag (such as [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)), I can see newer question

(Obviously using Newest sorting)

Comment: Related: [Searching help pages is broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408970/1364007). Search in general is broken at the moment. Wider search which show the behaviour: [`is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq), [`is:a`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aa). It went bad some time around 13:10:27Z yesterday.

Comment: Is SO finally improving the search? It previously included a lot of useless results. Perhaps it's changed so it only returns useless results. It's more consistent this way.

Comment: Similar to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366733/not-getting-recent-results-in-intagsmine-search from a couple of weeks ago, but that was resolved in about 6 hours.