# Search query not working

Tags: support, questions, search

This may be a dumb question, but if I search something like:

```
is:q [java] created:2021-07-04
```

I get plenty of results.

But the same query does not work for today, that is:

```
is:q [java] created:2021-07-05
```

Displays zero results.

Comment: Very likely same issue as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408978/intagsmine-stopped-working-yesterday).